# How can i capture events related to listview in android

Tags: android, tabs

Using Sliding Tab layout i have implemented list view with two tabs.Each row in list view has three elements image,text and favorite icon.

My question is how can i know when the favorite icon is clicked not the text, currently i get only one click event for the entire row ?

Comment: onItemClickListener will accept a click on the entire row.   If you have views inside that row that expect to be clicked, then you'll have to create a custom adapter and override the getView() method.   Probably might need an array to hold the state of objects clicked so that when scrolling new objects enter the screen the values are not recycled

Comment: i am using custom array adapter, and have implemented onTouch event for image view and text view, problem i face is when i use onItemClickListener  over row i get row number but onTouch i am unable to index row any help would be appreciated

Comment: don't use onItemClickListener.  Within your adapter, simply set the onClickListener for the image, text or icon.  What I like to do is set the tag of the view, let's say the icon, with the position information - cursor index or whatever.  I do that in every row in the adapter.  Then in my clickListener for the icon, I can retrieve the tag and I know which position was clicked.